# Replace 4 of 5 consecutive backslashes with R regex

Tags: regex, json, r

I have a API output that needs to be sanitized before processed with fromJSON (jsonlite package). It looks like the following when viewed in an R console session:

```
\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \\\\\"
```

The API output already seems to escape all quotes, but the last part, there're two consecutive `\` (each escaped by one backslash) and the the `\"` following.

Please note that 3 backslashes in a row shouldn't be replaced because that's how URLs are indicated:

```
\"source\":\"<a href=\\\"http://twitter.com/download/android\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\">Twitter for Android</a>\"
```

Now which regex do I have to use to transform these 5 backslashes into one? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand correctly.  This seems to work

```
x <-  "\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \\\\\""
gsub("\\\\{2,}", "", x)
#[1] "\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \""

x1 <- '\"source\":\"<a href=\\\"http://twitter.com/download/android\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\">Twitter for Android</a>\"'

gsub("\\\\{2,}", "", x1)
#[1] "\"source\":\"<a href=\\\"http://twitter.com/download/android\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\">Twitter for Android</a>\""
```

#### Update

Consider these cases:

```
 x2 <-  "\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \""
 x3 <-  "\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \\\""
 x4 <-  "\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \\\\\""
```

In the `x2`, `\"` is escaping the `"`.  In `x3`, there is only one `\` before the escape `\"` and in `x4` it is `2`.  You can look at how it is printed.  For example

```
 cat('\\', '\n')
 #\ 

 cat('\\\\', '\n')
 #\\
```

So, by specifying `{3,}` would not work as it is less than `3`

```
 gsub('\\\\{2,}', "", x4)
 #[1] "\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \""

 gsub('\\\\{2,}', "", x3) # the number is less
 #[1] "\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \\\""
 gsub('\\\\', "", x3)
 #[1] "\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \""
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work! But why does `"\\\\{2,}"` not match three or five backslashes? As far as I understood, {2,} matches the preceeding item 2 or more times, so two (escaped) backslashes or more. Am I completely wrong?

Comment: So one premise was correct (that `"\\\\{2,}"` matches 3 backslashes)  but the other premise (that you had three backslashes) was false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following in the call to gsub if I understand you correctly.

```
x <- "\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \\\\\""
gsub('\\\\\\\\\\"', '\\"', x)
# [1] "\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \""
```

Or the following should suffice.

```
gsub('\\\\\\\\', '', x)
# [1] "\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \""
```

**Note:** This will retain the three backslashes indicated in the urls and only replace the unwanted backslashes.

Comment: Yes, this also works, thanks! Am I corrent that `gsub("\\\\\\\\", "", x)` doesn't work the way your answer with single quotes does?

Answer (score 0):

try this with python and regex:

```
import re

yourstring = '\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \\\\\"'
print(re.sub(r'(.+)(\\")', r'\1"', yourstring))
```

prints the follwing:

```
\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \"
```

Use the regex in the language or flavour of your predilection.

Comment: why would you answer this question in python rather than java, sas macro, or ancient greek?

Comment: palabras necias, oídos sordos

Answer (score 0):

In R, the backslash is an escape character (as it also in in regex), so this is an R backslash:

```
bslash <- "\\"
```

Test it:

```
> nchar(bslash)
[1] 1
```

So unless you post whatever you are seeing in an R session, I'm not going to be very clear about what you really expect. If I make a file with that string as its contents and then read it into R I see:

```
> readLines(con="BStxt.txt")
[1] "\\\"text\\\":\\\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \\\\\\\\\\\""
```

So ... maybe .... you should double every backslash in the pattern argument to your  gsub() call. But wait... maybe that last "\"" is really an escaped double quote? (Since if you count out the number of paired back-slashed, you end up with a solitary one before the final `"`).

```
# Using the paired single quotes to delimit 
# .... but unsure that will be the same as what you see.
> test <- '\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text \\\\\"'
[1] "\"text\":\"RT @petertauber: Some random text "
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I thought I made it clear, but I will be more precicely: I executed my API-call in R and saved it in a variable `x`. The output I posted was c&p from the RStudio console when just typing `x`. But see answer by @akrun which seems to solve it.

Comment: He guessed right and I guessed wrong. I guessed that you were importing that text from an external source. I edited you question to reflect this which is what you should have done in the first place and even now so that people coming ot this question later will have a solid basis for understanding.